# Append an output from program to a file bash script

Tags: bash

I have to execute programs for several times in bash shell like the following:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do time ./a.out; done
```

Each iteration generates the following output:

```
Start
Stop

real   0m1.112s
user   0m1.112s  
sys    0m0.00s
```

I need to append a real part from this output (generated at each iteration) i.e. 0m1.112s (extracted from real   0m1.112s) to some output file. The final output may look like the following:

```
1.112s, 1.113s, 1.112s, 1.113s, 1.112s
```

I made a C program for this and it works perfectly but the problem is that it generates some overhead and produces a little more variation in execution times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do:

```
for((i=0;i<10;i++)) do 
{ time ./a.out >/dev/null; } 2>&1 
done | awk '{ORS=","; if($1=="real") print $2}'
```

- `time` outputs to *stderr* so `2>&1` will send stderr to stdout.
- `>/dev/null` will discard the actual output, if any, as you are only interested in `time`'s output.
- In the awk part, it'll print the 2nd column value if first column is `"real"` with `ORS` setting the output separator to `,` so that all the outputs are in a single line.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thanks. Is it possible that we can further extract only the seconds part i.e. instead of 0m1.122s, only 1.122s is printed.

Comment: In the awk part you could do: `... | awk '{ if($1=="real") print substr($2,0,length($2))}` to cut the last char (which is `s`).

Comment: I meant the removal of 0m (from the start).

Comment: @Shahzad Sorry. For some reason I thought you wanted to remove `s`. This will remove the `0m`s:  `.. | awk -F'm' '/real/{ORS=","; print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

A bash only solution:

```
for i in {1..10}; do time ./a.out 2&>1 > /dev/null ; done |
(
  # Collect data
  values=()
  while read key value; do
      [[ "$key" == "real" ]] && values+=( "$value" )
  done;

  # produce output
  IFS=, ; echo "${values[*]}" 
)
```